# What triple pedal to use for Thomann DP-26?

Tags: audio

I want to buy a pedal box for my digital piano. What is the best one for a Thomann piano? I need it to have a big single cable that goes under the keyboard (not the classic "headphone" jack). Also, I would prefer one that has
"half-damper" effect.

Comment: I'm not going to vote to close since it is still a hardware recommendation, but this seems to fall into a weird gap between https://music.stackexchange.com and here and–even if it is on topic here–I'm afraid you might not get the help you seek. I myself don't think I have the technical background to give a good recommendation here.

Comment: I was asking on https://music.stackexchange.com/ but they said that they don't discuss product reccomendations.

Comment: Yeah I saw that :/ It's possible that a non-SE site is where you'll want to go.